# The merge process could not connect to the Publisher 'Server:Reports'. Check to ensure that the server is running

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Sql version:Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
Replication type: Merge

Getting Below error in 'View Synchronization Status' window.

**The merge process could not connect to the Publisher 'Server:Reports'. Check to ensure that the server is running.**

Though Replication is working Fine as i can see records are replicating successfully from publisher to subscriber.
User Permissions looks all good as i have provided db_owner roles.
What else i can check?

Comment: I followed steps mentioned on this article

 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ca964d66-8905-4fbc-aea9-65a72bbe5602/the-merge-process-could-not-connect-to-the-publisher?forum=sqlreplication

not sure how to do 'check db_owner for repl_merge agent'

Comment: Also getting below error in sql agent logs



Replication-Replication Merge Subsystem: agent T09-Reports-Reports Publicatio-t0A-10 failed. The merge process could not connect to the Publisher 'T09:Reports'. Check to ensure that the server is running.
Error: 14151, Severity: 18, State: 1.

Comment: Account is having Db_owner rights.

I observed few orphan jobs under SQLserver agent(which i created in past for testing), in sql server agent logs there were number of error for these jobs. I cleaned up all unnecessary orphan jobs and restarted agent and after that ERROR 'The merge process could not connect 'resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I observed few orphan jobs under SQLserver agent(which i created in past for testing), in sql server agent logs there were number of error for these jobs. I cleaned up all unnecessary orphan jobs and restarted agent and after that ERROR 'The merge process could not connect 'resolved.